# Native messages in Chrome Extension not working

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I use native message for sending data to my desktop application. But, my extension can't connect to my application host, if I not added key in my manifest file. When I insert key in Manidest.json, I can't published my extension on Chrome Store, and received error "Key field value in the manifest doesn't match the current item."
Can somebody help me?

Comment: The `key` value in manifest forces a specific id of your extension, that's all it does so instead of using this key you can modify the native host's manifest and add your current extension's id there.

Comment: wOxxOm
Thank You.
It helped me a lot